# Refactor in next js and typescript api

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm beginner in next js and typescript. I want to do is refactoring to improve data fetching speed.

I have dashboard.tsx with follwing code

```
import Layout from "@/layouts/layout";
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { LanguageContext } from "@/hooks/Lang/LanguageContext";
import Card from "@/components/Cards/dashboardCard";
import Link from "next/link";
import {
  editData,
  getMultipleData,
  getSingleData,
} from "@/lib/ApiRequestHelper";
import DepositWithdrawTable from "@/components/Table/DepositWithdrawTable";
import PerformanceTable from "@/components/Table/PerformanceTable";
import { checkUserRoles } from "@/lib/checkUserRole";
import Spinner from "@/components/Spinner/Spinner";
import GeneralOutcomeTable from "@/components/Table/GeneralOutcomeTable";

type ReportData = {
  data: {
    amount: number;
    confirmStatus: number;
    id: number;
    reporter: {
      id: number;
      name: string;
    };
    type: string;
    [key: string]: any; // To account for any additional properties
  };
};


const Dashboard = () => {
  const { t } = useContext(LanguageContext);
  const [income, setIncome] = useState<number>(0);
  const [outcome, setOutcome] = useState<number>(0);
  const [regularData, setRegularData] = useState<ReportData[]>([]);
  const [balanceData, setBalanceData] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [userCount, setUserCount] = useState(0);
  const [reportsCount, setReportsCount] = useState(0);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [userRole, setUserRole] = useState<string>("");
  const [data, setData] = useState<ReportData[]>([]); // Initialize as an empty array

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const [fetchFinancial, fetchUsers, fetchReports, fetchUncheckReports, fetchRegularData, role] = await Promise.all([
      getMultipleData("/calculations"),
      getMultipleData("/users"),
      getMultipleData("/reports"),
      getMultipleData("/uncheck-reports"),
      getMultipleData('/general-outcome'),
      checkUserRoles()
    ]);
    try {

      setUserCount(fetchUsers.data.length);
      setReportsCount(fetchReports.meta.totalItems);
      setIncome(fetchFinancial.data.income);
      setOutcome(fetchFinancial.data.outcome);
      setBalanceData(fetchFinancial.data);
      setData(fetchUncheckReports.data);
      setRegularData(fetchRegularData.data);
      setUserRole(role);
      setLoading(false);

    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const handleAccept = async (id: number) => {
    await editData(`/reports/${id}/accept`, "");
    fetchData();
  };

  const handleReject = async (id: number) => {
    await getSingleData(`/reports/${id}/reject`);
    fetchData();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        {loading ? (
          <Spinner />
        ) : (
          <div className="">
            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" className="w-full p-4 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-100 pl-8">
              <ol className="flex h-8 space-x-2 dark:text-gray-100">
                <li className="flex items-center">
                  <Link rel="noopener noreferrer" href="/app/home" title="Back to homepage" className="flex items-center hover:underline"><i className="fa-solid fa-house" /></Link>
                </li>
                <li className="flex items-center space-x-1">
                  <span className="dark:text-gray-400">/</span>
                  <Link rel="noopener noreferrer" href="/app/dashboard" className="flex items-center px-1 capitalize hover:underline">Dashboard</Link>
                </li>
              </ol>
            </nav>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-4 gap-3 p-8">
              <div className="w-full sm:w-full md:w-1/4 p-2">
                <Link href="/app/reports">
                  <Card title={t("income")} data={income} />
                </Link>
              </div>
              <div className="w-full sm:w-full md:w-1/4 p-2">
                <Link href="/app/reports">
                  <Card title={t("outcome")} data={outcome} />
                </Link>
              </div>
              <div className="w-full sm:w-full md:w-1/4 p-2">
                <Link href="/app/reports">
                  <Card title={t("reports")} data={reportsCount} />
                </Link>
              </div>
              <div className="w-full sm:w-full md:w-1/4 p-2">
                <Link href="/app/users">
                  <Card title={t("users")} data={userCount} />
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-5 p-8">
              <div className="w-full">
                <DepositWithdrawTable
                  onAccept={handleAccept}
                  onReject={handleReject}
                  data={data}
                  userRole={userRole}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="w-full">
                <PerformanceTable
                  balanceData={balanceData}
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-5 p-8">
              <div className="w-full">
                <GeneralOutcomeTable data={regularData} userRole={userRole} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

In this file , there are many parallel fetching api data. So , when i go that page , screen loading take a lot of time. I want to refactor that code to improve data fetching.So, please let me know to improve speed or refactoring way.Thank you for your consideration.

This is getMultipleData function

```
import { callApi } from '@/hooks/callApi'

const defaultRoute = '/api/app';

export async function getMultipleData(url: string) {
  return await callApi('get', defaultRoute + url)
}
```

P.S I'm using laravel for backend.And please let me know if there is any improving my coding pattern .

I tried useMemo from react , that is related or not what I want, I'm not sure tho.

Answer (score 0):

There are some suggestions I have for a more sleeky and optimized code:

1. Try using Promise.allSettelled feature in JavaScript in order to handle several API calls more efficiently.
2. As far as I can see you can at least handle some of your states in one by saving them as an object and then just updating only one property.
3. I recommend you use Axios library for API calls